# How to identify Worklight adapter calls in IBM HTTP Server logs?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibmhttpserver

Trying to identify worklight adapter requests from web server access logs, but all the requests look really generic. Any idea how to identify adapter requests?

The Request only contains `"POST /Worklight/apps/services/api/MobileApp/android/query HTTP 1.1"`. I 
can't see the adapter name nor procedure name.

Comment: Out of the box, you can't inspect the body and set environment variables. It would require a custom input filter.    Those are quite tricky because the input streams in, and to find a string you'd have to worry about it spanning multiple incoming buckets of data.

Do you know how large the POST is?  It's possible something like mod_substitute could be extended or copied to "check" a body.

Answer (score 2):

while this query is indeed an adapter invocation , the adapter name, method and parameters are embedded into the POST HTTP message body. its not a big  payload (less than 1KB).
I'm not an IHS log expert, but maybe there is a way to log also message body.
( I saw this un-answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354942)

However, if you upgrade to newer MFP version (v7.0+) then you can expose adapters as a RESTfull service. This will make the IHS logs much more clear which adapter was called (each one has different URL).